# python: check any number of nested list to conclude if empty or not

Tags: python

so basically I'm trying to create a function that will check a list which may or may not contain many nested layers of lists, to see if they are all empty.

so

`empty([])` will return true so will `empty([['']])` and so will `empty([[[]]])`

I've tried

```
def empty(seq):
     try:
         return all(map(empty, seq))
     except TypeError:
         return False
```

but running into `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error when I run this.

The problematic case string is this : `["[u'3D Blu-ray Disc\\u2122 Player (BD-D7500)']"]` I have no idea why that is causing this problem

```
["[u'3D Blu-ray Disc\\u2122 Player (BD-D7500)']"]
maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dashboard.py", line 583, in download
    return get_rows_from_db(str(job.id), job.url,taskid, options,trial)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 123, in get_rows_from_db
    print "B " + empty(col)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in empty
    for item in seq)
  File "./dashboard.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    for item in seq)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/abc.py", line 132, in __instancecheck__
    if subclass is not None and subclass in cls._abc_cache:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py", line 73, in __contains__
    return wr in self.data
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Comment: `empty([[[]]])` shouldn't return true, as only the innermost list is empty.  The outer two lists do contain something -- another list.  I think you need better requirements.

Comment: yes but they are all empty lists so I want to detect such cases and conclude as 'empty'. only if they contain non empty values should it return false

Comment: You're function doesn't work because you never return `True`. What happens when you add the line `if not seq: return True` at the beginning?

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error you are having. Please provide the expect and actual output. See [ask], but especially [mcve] for more information.

Comment: @Robᵩ the culprit was the this raw string from the wild `["[u'3D Blu-ray Disc\\u2122 Player (BD-D7500)']"]` not sure why it's failing for that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function satisfies each of the test cases you provide.

```
import collections


def empty(seq):
    if isinstance(seq, basestring):
        return seq == ''
    return all(empty(item)
               if isinstance(item, collections.Sequence)
               else False
               for item in seq)

assert empty([])
assert empty([['']])
assert empty([[[]]])
assert not empty([[[], 1]])
assert empty(u'')
assert not empty(u'1')
assert not empty(["[[u'3D Blu-ray Disc\\u2122 Player (BD-D7500)']"])
```

Comment: `for item in seq)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/abc.py", line 132, in __instancecheck__
    if subclass is not None and subclass in cls._abc_cache:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py", line 73, in __contains__
    return wr in self.data
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp`

Comment: My example runs without error on Python 2.7.6 running on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. In what environment do you get an error?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a recursive data structure?

Comment: yeah it's possible trying to find out why

Comment: so when you pass `empty(["[u'3D Blu-ray Disc\\u2122 Player (BD-D7500)']"])`, it goes absolutely berserk reaching `maximum recursion depth` I included the error log in the original question.

Comment: Yep, so does `assert not empty(u'1')`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
def empty(L_or_I):
    if not L_or_I:
       return True
    if isinstance(L_or_I,(list,tuple)):
       return all(empty(x) for x in L_or_I)
    return False
```

I guess ... maybe

Answer (score 1):

If a list of 0 is an "empty", Joran answer is certainly correct.

If you only want to check iterable, I would suggest:

```
import collections
def empty(e):
    if not isinstance(e, collections.Iterable):
        return False
    if not e:
        return True
    return all(empty(x) for x in e)
```